# How to set all values of an object to null in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to set all properties of some object to `null`.
But the object can be very big, so I can't just do it one by one.

How to set all properties at once?

Comment: Wondering if there's an ES6 way to do this

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here's a useful function called 'Object.keys()', it returns all of the attribute names of an object.

```
let setAll = (obj, val) => Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = val);
let setNull = obj => setAll(obj, null);
```

Non-arrow-function version:

```
function setAll(obj, val) {
    /* Duplicated with @Maksim Kalmykov
        for(index in obj) if(obj.hasOwnProperty(index))
            obj[index] = val;
    */
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(index) {
        obj[index] = val
    });
}
function setNull(obj) {
    setAll(obj, null);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reference for `Object.keys`. Also, please use correct terminology. "Attributes" is incorrect. Finally, if you're going to get all functional, shouldn't you define the function as `setAll = val => obj =>...`, and then `const setNull = setAll(null);`?

Comment: This answer still does not set all the values "at once". It loops over the properties.

Comment: @torazaburo I ain't saying it's funtional... Just with arrow functions lol (btw it's nearly impossible to set'em 'all at once')

Answer (score 22):

If you are looking for a short one-liner to copy and paste, use this

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach((i) => obj[i] = null);
```

Answer (score 8):

Another way of doing it, using `Array.reduce`. It does not overwriting the existing object. This only works if the object only have simple values.

```
const newObj = Object.keys(originalObj).reduce(
  (accumulator, current) => {
    accumulator[current] = null; 
    return accumulator
  }, {});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Object.keys()` as Nianyi Wang mentioned in his answer, or a `for in`, like this:

```
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        obj[key] = null;
    }
}
```

But in this case you should check `hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: I thought so, too. But OP didn't want to loop b/c object could be huge. I think @user663031 idea is plausible. Just create a new object.

Comment: ESLint throws an error `no-prototype-builtins` when calling `hasOwnProperty` directly on an object. One can use 
`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)` instead to silence it.

Answer (score 4):

> But the object can be very big, so I can't just do it one by one.

By "big" do you mean "millions of properties" and you are concerned about performance? Or do you mean "a bunch of properties you don't know the names of, and/or don't want to have list out"?

> How to set all properties at once?

You can't. One way or another, you have to loop.

Instead of mutating an existing object, consider creating a new, empty object. Its property values will be `undefined`, but that could work depending on your code structure.

Answer (score 3):

If object contains child object, if you want to set all child object properties to null, recursive solution is below.

```html
function setEmpty(input){

    let keys = Object.keys(input);

        for( let key of keys ){

             if(typeof input[key] != "object" ){
                 input[key] = null;
             }else{
                 setEmpty(input[key]);
             }
        }
        return input;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Lodash can manage this using `cloneDeepWith`.

My solution to the same problem:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
const bigObj = {"big": true, "deep": {"nested": {"levels": "many" } } };
const blankObj = _.cloneDeepWith(bigObj, (value) => {return _.isObject(value) ? undefined : null});
console.log(blankObj);
// outputs { big: null, deep: { nested: { levels: null } } }
```

Returning `undefined` in the customizer was not obvious to me, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52956848/215237) explains that doing so triggers recursion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) & [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) like this

```
Object.fromEntries(
  Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [key, null])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `for in`. Here is an example:

```
let obj = {prob1:"value1", prob2:"value2"}
for(let prob in obj){obj[prob]=null}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
export const setObjToNull = (obj) => {
    var returnObj = {};
    Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
        let nullObj = { [key]: '' };
        Object.assign(returnObj, nullObj);
    })
    return returnObj;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```html
let values = {
    a:1, 
    b:'', 
    c: {
        a:'', 
        s:4, 
        d: {
            q: '',
            w: 8,
            e: 9
        }
 
    }
}


values;

const completeWithNull = (current) => {
  Object.keys(current).forEach((key) => {
     current[key] = current[key] === ''? null 
     : typeof current[key] === 'object' ? completeWithNull(current[key])
     : current[key]
  });
  
  return current;
};

completeWithNull(values);
```