# Reset the values ​of an assosiative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an associative array with the following format:

```
var array = [{"id": "28", "name": "Josh"}, {"id": "17", "name": "Karl"}];
```

Is there any way to empty the key values ​​of each array index?

I've done it this way, but I don't know if it's the best:

```
array.forEach(item => {

  item.id = "";
  item.name = "";

})
```

Comment: In your `forEach`, consider: [How to set all values of an object to null in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897879/how-to-set-all-values-of-an-object-to-null-in-javascript) (instead of `null`, use `""`).

Comment: There are no associative arrays in JavaScript. An array always has numerically indexed properties and is denoted by `[` and `]` when written as a literal. A *JavaScript object* has key-value pairs and is denoted by `{` and `}` when written as a literal. The two are different and objects are *not* arrays.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do this? As opposed to removing the objects?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want to do this so as not to eliminate the array, and to be able to maintain its format for a next use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're doing it is fine if you really want to have blank strings as the `id` and `name` of all of the objects. A slightly more modern approach would use an ES2015+ `for-of` loop, and you can use a single statement to set both values if you like:

```
for (const item of array ) {
    item.id = item.name = "";
}
```

But again, your `forEach` loop is fine, and works in environments that have `forEach` but don't have `for-of`.

Comment: Also as an alternative, all object entries can just be wiped out and set to a `{}`. But then you lose the property names, so not sure if that's really needed, hence mentioning it as a comment.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that method.