# Set Javascript object values to null

Tags: javascript, dictionary, javascript-objects

I'm fairly new to js. Is there a way to set all the values of keys (fields) in a JS object to null? Without doing it manually one by one? Because the object is large.
I've tried using `Object.values(obj) == null` but it doesn't work.
I've read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897879/how-to-set-all-values-of-an-object-to-null-in-javascript),
but I can't understand how is it setting the values to null. I think it's just looping over them. Am I wrong?

Comment: [`Object.prototype.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) + [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Yes it loops through the properties of the object and sets them to null.

Comment: @Mick I've tried using it. It does loop over them but isn't setting them to null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fastest and most readable way in my opinion:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key]=null);
```

Object.keys retrieve all the keys from a given object, and then just iterate through to set them to null.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (const field in object) object[field] = null
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not mutate the original object, make a copy, return and use it.

```
createEmptyValues(obj){ 
  let copyObj = {...obj};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(copyObj)) {
    if(Array.isArray(copyObj[key])){
      // if set array to empty then use copyObj[key] = [];
      // if set individual keys of your array to empty, do below
      for (let index = 0; index < copyObj[key].length; index++) {
        copyObj[key][index] = this.createEmptyValues(copyObj[key][index]); 
      }
    } else {
      switch(typeof value){
        case 'string':
        copyObj[key] = '';
        break;
        case 'number':
        copyObj[key] = '';
        break;
        case 'boolean':
        copyObj[key] = false;
        break;
        case 'object':
        if(value !== null){
          copyObj[key] = this.createEmptyValues(value);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return copyObj;
}
```